# AWS ELB + PHP nginx nodejs sessions

Tags: php, node.js, amazon-web-services, nginx

I currently am scaling an web app behind the aws elb. Currently all the frontend nodes im load balancing inbetween have php+nginx to serve the web app, and node.js to server the websockets. The nginx forwards the request to the node server on a specific port.

My question is, I'm using tcp load balancing so its not sticky, when the user logs in and is routed to another server from where they are logged into their session dissapears and have to relog?

How do I prevent this from happening or implement a solution so that regardless of the node they are routed to, they remember the users session?

Comment: do you need to use tcp load balancing for some other reason? Otherwise, use http or https and turn on stickiness.  If you can't do that, you'll need to use database-driven sessions.